# Conexões websockets com PHP

Tags: php, websocket

Estou a usar [essa classe](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php) para trabalhar com WebSockets no PHP junto ao HTML5 e possuo duas duvidas sobre as conexões.

- Como eu posso listar todas as conexões ativas naquele servidor?
- Como eu posso desconectar uma conexão apenas, por exemplo, eu estou na conexão X e quero desconectar Y?

Comment: Parece que a resposta do old7 indica o caminho das pedras, mas dá para ser mais preciso se você mostrar o que está fazendo. Pode [edit] a pergunta com um exemplo do seu uso da classe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public $wsClients = array();
```

e

```
function wsRemoveClient($clientID)
```